# Emulator restart continuously Android Studio 3.1.4?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio version 3.1.4. Android Studio Emulator gives "Guest isn't online after...      Dismiss" 
and then after a few seconds, the emulator is started working well.
If I run my project a few times, Emulator keeps on restarting. Closing and reopening, uninstall and reinstalling Android Emulator and HAXM from SDK tools does not fix the issue. I was wondering if someone has a solution for this issue. Thanks

Comment: I also faced same Issue Its mostly possible due to Less RAM size.. After increasing my Ram to 8 gb now its fixed

Comment: I give one advice, I faced the same difficulty trying to uninstall Android Studio Proper way 1>uninstall from the control panel 2> delete an android folder from programming files on C: drive 3>delete folder  C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Android and install android studio